# Lenovo Hotkeys Bad Bios, Disabling Hotkeys

Tags: windows-8, bios

How do I disable hotkey keys, this suddenly stopped working for me, enable or disbled, its stuck on Fn lock mode

**Setting hotkey mode**

By default, the hotkey functions are accessible by pressing the appropriate hotkey. However, you can disable the hotkey mode in the BIOS setup utility. To disable the hotkey mode:

Shut down the computer.
Press the Novo button and then select BIOS Setup.
In the BIOS setup utility, open the Configuration menu, and change the setting of HotKey Mode from Enabled to Disabled.
Open the Exit menu, and select Exit Saving Changes.